# react button sending data to back end but doesn't do anything in front end/ logs things in the console

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, axios, jwt

I'm making a login page but when I push the login button the function does run (I think) because in the node.js server I get the data in the console and it also says it sends the data back to the front end I check this in insomnia and there I get the response but on on my react site I nothing happens and nothing logs in the console even though I'm sure it does something and I log a lot. here is my code for the react function for the log in:

```
  const login = () => {
    const data = { username: username, password: password };
    console.log(data);
    axios
      .post(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGIN, data, {
        headers: {
          serveraccessToken: localStorage.getItem("serveraccessToken"),
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("eah");
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.error) {
          setPostObject(response.data);
          console.log(response.data.error);
        } else {
          console.log(response.data.succes);
          localStorage.setItem("useraccessToken", response.data.succes.token);
          setAuthState({
            username: response.data.username,
            id: response.data.id,
            status: true,
          });
          navigate("/");
        }
        console.log(response.data);
      });
  };
```

This is the part in the html part of the react code where the button is pushed to log in:

```
        <div className="error-message"> {postObject.error} </div>
        <button class="button1" onClick={login}>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </button>
        <button class="button2">Sign Up</button>
```

for the back end I use the following code:

```
router.post("/login", verifyserver, async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(username);

  var user = await Users.findOne({
    where: { username: username },
  });
  if (user == null) {
    var user = await Users.findOne({
      where: { email: username },
    });
  }

  console.log(emailuser);
  if (!user) {
    res.json({ error: "password or username incorrect" });
  }
  if (user) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((match) => {
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        { username: user.username, id: user.id },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET_USER
      );
      console.log(accessToken);
      if (!match) res.json({ error: "password or username incorrect" });
      else if (user.emailverification == 0)
        res.json({ error: "please verify email adress" });
      else {
        console.log("success");
        res.json({
          succes: { token: accessToken, username: username, id: user.id },
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The verify server part is a jwt token so that you can only access the server from the site (I copied the token thats why it works in insomnia) here is the code of how I get the server token in the react front end:

```
const checkservertoken = (pw) => {
  axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_GETOKEN, pw).then((response) => {
    if (response.error) {
      console.log("server error");
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("serveraccessToken", response.data);
    }
  });
};

    const data = { pw: process.env.REACT_APP_PW };
    const serverAccessToken = localStorage.getItem("serveraccessToken");
    if (!serverAccessToken) {
      checkservertoken(data);
    }
```

I tried editing this that it doesn't get it every time the server loads thinking that the problem might be there but I couldn't get it work correctly and get the login part to work.

Thanks in advance for the help!!